# javascript string interpreted as object

Tags: javascript, string

Probably irrelevant from a production standpoint, but I'd like to know why this behaves the way it does. The string literal gets interpreted as an object.

```
function fancyCallback(callback) {
  callback(this);
  console.log(typeof this); // just to see it really is an object
}

fancyCallback.call('string here', console.log);
```

I have to call

```
this.toString()
```

inside the function if I want the expected output. I know strings are objects in javascript (which is lovely) but in a simple console.log('abc'), they are naturally interpreted as strings. Why is that? Is this useful in any way? Please ignore the fact that fancyCallback is defined in the global scope!

Comment: I believe it is because of the way variable definitions are in js.

Comment: `console.log()` simply calls the toString method on the string

Comment: this returns false: `(function() {return this;}).call('string here')==='string here'` Maybe the object was modified in some way.

Comment: @levi I added `console.log(this)` to his function, Chrome displayed `String {0: "s", 1: "t", 2: "r", 3: "i", 4: "n", 5: "g", 6: " ", 7: "h", 8: "e", 9: "r", 10: "e", length: 11, formatUnicorn: function, truncate: function, splitOnLast: function, contains: function}`.

Comment: @levi that is not true, try deleting the typeof keyword inside the function so it says console.log(this). it does not call toString() on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MDN call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

> `thisArg`
>
> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this
>   may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>   function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced
>   with the global object, and ***primitive values will be boxed***.

Primitives [aka numbers/strings] are placed into a container object, so it is working just like you are seeing it.

So what it is basically doing is

```
> var x = "string";
> typeof x
"string"
> var temp = new String(x);
> typeof temp
"object"
```

Comment: never heard the term "boxed"! honestly, I just love javascript even more for this. thanks!

Comment: added a little bit more of an explanation

Comment: [OOP Boxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming))