# javascript text interpreted as a script

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I do not understand the error that comes back to me the browser
I put some simple text into a variable
but in fact, this is interpreted as a script?

error :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token : line 10`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<body>
</body>
<script>

var text = '<script> Hello </script>' ;

//console.log ( text ); 

</script>
</html>
```

similar issues:
[javascript string interpreted as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412858/javascript-string-interpreted-as-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the browser is parsing that, it sees `<script>` and blindly builds up text until it sees the sequence `</script>`, which it then takes as the end of the script. In your case, that's in the middle of your string.

To avoid that, add a backslash in the string before the `/`:

```
var text = '<script> Hello <\/script>' ;
```

That backslash has no effect in JavaScript (an escaped `/` is still a `/`), but the browser won't see that as the end of the script.

Or you can break it up:

```
var text = '<script> Hello <' + '/script>' ;
```

Basically anything so that the browser doesn't see `</script>` prior to the actual end of your script.

Comment: the error is due to an attempt to enter into CodeMirror setValue a text which contains <script> </ script>, so I have to make a change in the sequence / with \ / for all text? thanks anyway

Comment: @marco: Only `</script>`. But the better answer is to put your JavaScript in JavaScript files and use `<script src="filename.js"></script>` instead. Then you don't have to worry about having the string `</script>` in your JavaScript code at all.

Comment: perfect , thanx a lot !